# Webpack CommonsChunkPlugin migration with 2 named commons chunks, 50+ entries

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

We're finally working on transitioning our code-base to Webpack 4, but are having some troubles replicating the setups we currently have with `CommonsChunkPlugin` and using the new `splitChunks` options.
Our webpack build looks something like this:

```js
const config = {
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'jquery',
            './libs/global',
            './css/forms.css'
            // ...
        ],
        angular: [
            'angular-timeago',
            'angular-cookies',
            'angular-messages',
            'angular-sanitize',
            'angular-animate',
            './libs/angular-common',
            // ...
        ],
        app1: ['./apps/app1/app'],
        app2: ['./apps/app2/app'],
        app3: ['./apps/app3/app'],
        app4: ['./apps/app4/app'],
        appWithoutAngular: ['./apps/app5/app'],
        app2WithoutAngular: ['./apps/app6/app'],
        // ... (50+ entries, some angular, some not)
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor'),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'angular',
            chunks: _.without(_.keys(config.entry), 'vendor', 'appWithoutAngular', 'app2WithoutAngular'), // exclude all non-angular entry points
            minChunks: 2
        }))
    ]
}
```

The concept is that we include the `vendor` bundle on *every* page on our website, plus any other entires, and then on pages that need angular, we also include the `angular` bundle, and any other entries needed. We don't load any chunks asynchronously and haven't found a good configuration for doing this.

We've attempted the following:

```js
config.optimization = {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
            vendors: false,
            vendor: {
                chunks: 'initial',
                priority: 10,
                name: 'vendor_test',
                reuseExistingChunk: true
            },
            angular: {
                chunks: 'initial',
                minChunks: 2,
                name: 'angular_test',
                enforce: true,
                reuseExistingChunk: true,
                test: function(module, chunks){
                    return chunks.some(function(chunk){
                        return nonAngularChunks.includes(chunk.name);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

But that seems to generate a 3+MB `vendor_test` chunk (we're used to about 100kb), and no `angular_test` chunk whatsoever. Ideally, and as how it worked in Webpack 3, we'd want to replace the `vendor` and `angular` entry points with the necessary dependencies, as determined by all of our non-angular chunks, and then angular chunks, respectively.

I've still not found a way to accomplish this with Webpack 4, and am hoping to find a solution soon.